# How to speed up sorting JTable with model that using OracleCachedRowSet?

Tags: java, performance, swing, sorting, jtable

I am using JTable with model that holds the data in `cachedRowSet` with `OracleCachedRowSet` implemetation .
In the `getValueAt()` method, I need to use the `cachedRowSet.absolute()` method in order to move the rowSet pointer to the desired line.
It seems that the `cachedRowSet.absolute()` is very slow and when I am sorting table (using java default sorter) with a lot of lines it makes the sorting process so slow that it can take few seconds.

Does anyone have a solution how to speed up the the sorting process (is there a way not to use `absolute()` in `getValueAt()` or speed up the `absolute()` method)?

Here is an example of `getValueAt()` that use the `absloute()` method:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    try {
      if (!rowSet.absolute(row + 1)) {
        return null;
      }
      return rowSet.getObject(col + 1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CachedRowSet.absolute()` may not be the reason for slowness, since it is loading from memory. `CachedRowSet` according to http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/chapter5.html, may not be the right tool for huge data sets, but once you have your `CachedRecordSet`, it is the Java default sorter that is responsible for the sorting.

Give it a try with [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/). Take a peek at a [comparison between these (two LGPL and one public domain) packages](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/sortedjtables/).